# Pass arguments to CreateThread() via struct and change a member for following threads without affecting the previous threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

This one is doing my head in. I'm trying to multithread in my c++ code. I put all of my (many) arguments into a struct

```
struct ARGS{
   //argument definitions
};

ARGS funcArgs = //function arguments
```

and pass this to my function using

```
Handles[0] = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)myFunc,&funcArgs,0,NULL)
```

The function definition looks like

```
void myFunc( void *funcArgs_ ){
    ARGS *funcArgs = (ARGS*)funcArgs_;
    //do stuff here
}
```

I have successfully used this method already to create a separate thread to run my main function without my gui hanging. The problem that I'm running into now is that I want to have four separate threads running, and modify some of the input arguments between each new thread, but because it's being passed by pointer, it affects the computations being performed in the previous threads. I realise I could simply create a new variable of type ARGS and pass that to the second thread, but one of the arguments in funcArgs is a `vector<vector<double> >` of about 6GB of data, so I can't afford to copy it into a new struct, and it remains unchanged for each thread, so it would be a total waste of RAM to copy it.

I would be quite happy to create one data structure for large variables that do not need to be changed, and another for small ones that DO change, but `CreateThread` only takes a function of one argument, so I can't do this.

The other thing I thought I could do, is create a new variable of type ARGS, but get around the problem of copying data by doing

```
struct ARGS{
    vector<vector<double> > *hugeArrayPtr;
   //other argument definitions
};
```

but I tried this and I get "error C2100: illegal indirection" when I try to dereference the pointer. It turns out that this is because I use indices to iterate over the array (vector) elements, and when using a pointer to a vector, you need to use iterators instead. The trouble with doing this is that it would require a significant rewrite of my code, and I'm not entirely sure how to do it. So it would be very time-consuming and I may end up just causing more problems than I solve.

Ultimately, it may turn out that this is the only way, but I am hoping there is a simpler solution to this. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: As it's C++ you could use a `const` reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: @RogerRowland I didn't even realise you could use references in a struct to be honest. So I'm guessing you just use `const vector<vector<double> > &hugeArray` in the struct, and then when you assign a value to this member it will not be copied but can be used as though it was? Basically how it works when passing by reference into a function? I can't find a lot of information about doing this. Cheers.

Comment: Ok - it's best to create an initialising constructor for the `struct` to make it easier to assign initial values.

Comment: using reference - this is probably what you should be doing. Note that references can only be assigned on construction of ARGS

Comment: One note: If you can, use std::thread or Boost.Thread, they are much better to use than the raw win32 API. That said, there should be only a single cast in your code. That cast should be a static_cast that converts the void pointer passed to your thread function back to its original type. The fact that  you cast the function type just indicates that you didn't declare your thread function correctly, which you should fix instead of brute-forcing the mismatching pointer type into CreateThread.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to the thread function but, inside, create a struct of arguments with received information, copy all parametres. Actually you are sharing the same information for all threads.

```
void myFunc( void *funcArgs_ )
{
    ARGS funcArgs(*((ARGS*)funcArgs_));   // ARGS copy constructor
}
```

Besides, you must have in mind that this is a thread code, you have no insurance of parameters changing in main thread meanwhile you copy your arguments in thread. So, you can use a semaphore to ensure correct copy before continuing thread creation or use different arguments struct.

In main thread:

Create arguments struct for thread 1
   Execute thread 1
   Wait for semaphore
   Modify arguments values for thread 2
   Execute thread 2
   Wait for semaphore

In threads:

Copy arguments to local thread storage
   Active semaphore.

About `vector<vector<double> >` 6GB problem, I assume this information is common to all threads,so, include a pointer to it in ARGS struct as you said. Using ARGS copy constructor in thread you will not have problems getting this pointer from parametres ans use it later in thread.

```
struct ARGS{
    vector<vector<double> > *hugeArrayPtr;
    //other argument definitions

    ARGS(const ARGS & arg) :
        hugeArrayPtr(arg.hugeArrayPtr),
        // other argument copy
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Why a Semaphore and not a Mutex?

Comment: Ok, a mutex, the idea is waiting for thread safe args copying.

Comment: To be bluntly honest, I think that's a stupid idea. Copy the struct before(!) passing it to CreateThread, then you have a guarantee that they run without obstructing each other. Your approach just adds more complexity and costs more time.